# Drawing on Flex Chart

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, flash-builder

I've created a line chart in flex and it works like expected. Now, I would like to add shading to the background for specific information. For example, this chart - http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/graph/?id=TOTALSL,TOTALNS, - shows a shaded background for recessions. How would I mimic this shading in a Flex linechart?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw it in the background of the chart using the drawing api.

edit:

I dont know of any code examples on the web, I've only done it in production code (aka I cant share it, sorry :( )
you will want to create a container and put it into the charts

```
<mx:backgroundElements>
```

You should pass into this container the min and max for the x-axis probably as separate properties and a dataprovider that describes when to show a highlighted section.  You might have to compute the min and max based on the dataprovider you pass into the chart.

If you just want to show the highlighted area you will just use the drawing api and compute where to put on the x-axis based on your min, max, width of container, and data point (start and end values) from your dataprovider.  It will look something like this in your updateDisplayList:

```
// code is not tested but a good start

var shadeStartX:Number = (max-min)/startPoint; 
var shadeEndX:Number = (max-min)/endPoint;
var shadeWidth:Number = shadeEndX - shadeStartX;

...

this.graphics.drawRect(shadeStartX, 0, shadeWidth, unscaledHeight);
```

but if you want to have things like hover states and all that goodness I would suggest creating a display object that you pass the width in and adding that to the container at the computed x-axis to set it at.

Comment: Hi asawilliams. Thanks for your response. I figured there may be some drawing required. How would I tie the drawing of the background to correspond to the dates on the x axis as shown in the link I provided? Is there a generic charting example showing this? It would help greatly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! that looks like it points me in right direction. let me try it out

Comment: Thanks asa, I found this http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/overlayDemo/index.html which really helped out a lot in getting started. However, your input about the <mx:backgroundElements> added the finishing touches!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I feel that drawing something yourself is not the right way to go.
You should ideally use a PlotSeries inside the LineChart, and create a custom item renderer for each element in the series.

PlotSeries allows you to give your own custom image/object to draw at a specific date/point in the chart.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/series/PlotSeries.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_10.html

All the examples show the plotSeries with smaller objects but you can create an object which covers the chart vertically and has a constant width.